# Wordpress Gutenberg - Sidebar get posts list based on selected category

Tags: block-editor, sidebar, select

I need to display the complete posts list in the dropdown list in the custom block sidebar.

I used for that withSelect:

```
...
    const currentPostId = select('core/editor').getCurrentPostId();

    const query = {
                orderby : 'date',
                order : 'asc',
                status : 'publish',
                per_page: -1,
                exclude: currentPostId,
    }
    return {articleList: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'post', query)}

...
```

My issue is that I have a lot lot lot lot ... of posts and so it takes a life to get the list in my selectControl.

I so tried to reduce the number of retrieved posts by first selecting the list of categories (same king of code). But how can I so retrieve posts based on the selected category?

Thx!

Comment: Did you try: `category: [1,2,3],`

Comment: Maybe I should have been more precise: the category is displayed via a selectControl. The user needs first to select the category then the post list should be rendered.